# How to use an async function as the second parameter to jest.mock?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I need to use `jest.mock` together with `async`, `await` and `import()` so that I can use a function from another file inside the mocked module. Otherwise I must copy and paste a few hundreds of slocs or over 1000 slocs, or probably it is not even possible.

## An example

### This does work well:

```js
jest.mock('./myLin.jsx', () => {
  return {
    abc: 967,
  }
});
```

Everywhere I use abc later it has 967 as its value, which is different than the original one.

### This does not work:

```js
jest.mock('./myLin.jsx', async () => {
  return {
    abc: 967,
  }
});
```

`abc` seems to not be available.

### Actual issue

I need `async` to be able to do this:

```js
jest.mock('~/config', async () => {
  const { blockTagDeserializer } = await import(
    '../editor/deserialize' // or 'volto-slate/editor/deserialize'
  );

  // … here return an object which contains a call to
  // blockTagDeserializer declared above; if I can't do this
  // I cannot use blockTagDeserializer since it is outside of
  // the scope of this function
}
```

## Actual results

I get **errors** like:

> `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'slate' of '((cov_1viq84mfum.s[13]++) , _config.settings)' as it is undefined.`

where `_config`, I think, is the `~/config` module object and `slate` is a property that should be available on `_config.settings`.

## Expected results

No error, `blockTagDeserializer` works in the mocked module and the unit test is passed.

## The unit test code

The code below is a newer not-working code based on [this file on GitHub](https://github.com/eea/volto-slate/blob/3281496920f3b3ba234db8f995bbb725cb8863da/src/widgets/WysiwygWidget.test.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import WysiwygWidget from './WysiwygWidget';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-intl-redux';

const mockStore = configureStore();

global.__SERVER__ = true; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
global.__CLIENT__ = false; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle

jest.mock('~/config', async () => {
  const { blockTagDeserializer } = await import(
    '../editor/deserialize' // or 'volto-slate/editor/deserialize'
  );

  const createEmptyParagraph = () => {
    return {
      type: 'p',
      children: [{ text: '' }],
    };
  };
  return {
    settings: {
      supportedLanguages: [],
      slate: {
        elements: {
          default: ({ attributes, children }) => (
            <p {...attributes}>{children}</p>
          ),
          strong: ({ children }) => {
            return <strong>{children}</strong>;
          },
        },
        leafs: {},
        defaultBlockType: 'p',
        textblockExtensions: [],
        extensions: [
          (editor) => {
            editor.htmlTagsToSlate = {
              STRONG: blockTagDeserializer('strong'),
            };
            return editor;
          },
        ],
        defaultValue: () => {
          return [createEmptyParagraph()];
        },
      },
    },
  };
});

window.getSelection = () => ({});

test('renders a WysiwygWidget component', () => {
  const store = mockStore({
    intl: {
      locale: 'en',
      messages: {},
    },
  });
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <WysiwygWidget
        id="qwertyu"
        title="My Widget"
        description="My little description."
        required={true}
        value={{ data: 'abc <strong>def</strong>' }}
        onChange={(id, data) => {
          // console.log('changed', data.data);
          // setHtml(data.data);
        }}
      />
    </Provider>,
  );
  const json = component.toJSON();
  expect(json).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

## What I've tried

1. The code snippets above show partially what I have tried.
2. I searched the web for 'jest mock async await import' and did not found something relevant.

## The question

If `jest.mock` is not made to work with `async`, what else can I do to make my unit test work?

## Update 1

In the last snippet of code above, the line

```js
              STRONG: blockTagDeserializer('strong'),
```

uses `blockTagDeserializer` defined [here](https://github.com/eea/volto-slate/blob/3281496920f3b3ba234db8f995bbb725cb8863da/src/editor/deserialize.js#L65-L97) which uses `deserializeChildren`, `createEmptyParagraph` (which is imported from another module), `normalizeBlockNodes` (which is imported from another module) and `jsx` (which is imported from another module) functions, which use `deserialize` which uses `isWhitespace` which is imported from another module and `typeDeserialize` which uses `jsx` and `deserializeChildren`.

Without using `await import(...)` syntax how can I fully mock the module so that my unit test works?

If you want to dig into our code, please note that the `volto-slate/` prefix in the `import` statements is for the `src/` folder in the repo.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you should rather use a [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) instead

Comment: How is a setup file different from [beforeAll](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown)? Or how can a setup file help me?

Comment: What is the actual return value of `blockTagDeserializer('strong')`? And why can't you just mock it?

Comment: It is a function that uses other functions that use other functions etc.

Comment: That doesn't really clarify anything, but nevermind. I think you should mock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I have a `ref` callback that sets the `htmlTagsToSlate` property of the `editor` in the actual code of the module, conditioned by `global.__JEST__` which is defined as `true` in Jest command line usage:

```
import { htmlTagsToSlate } from 'volto-slate/editor/config';

[...]

testingEditorRef={(val) => {
  ref.current = val;
  if (val && global.__JEST__) {
    val.htmlTagsToSlate = { ...htmlTagsToSlate };
  }
}}
```

Now the `jest.mock` call for `~/config` is simple, there is no need to do an `import` in it.

I also use this function:

```js
const handleEditorRef = (editor, ref) => {
  if (typeof ref === 'function') {
    ref(editor);
  } else if (typeof ref === 'object') {
    ref.current = editor;
  }
  return editor;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise not doing any "heavy" stuff (whatever that means) in a callback of `jest.mock`, – it is designed only for mocking values.

Given your specific example, I'd just put whatever the output of `blockTagDeserializer('strong')` right inside the config:

```js
jest.mock('~/config', () => {
  // ...

        extensions: [
          (editor) => {
            editor.htmlTagsToSlate = {
              STRONG: ({ children }) => <strong>{children}</strong>, // or whatever this function actually returns for 'strong'
            };
            return editor;
          },
        ],

  // ...
});
```

This doesn't require anything asynchronous to be done.

If you need this setup to be present in a lot of files, extracting it in a [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) seems to be the next best thing.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details at the end. I need more help and I thank you for the help.